# Add param to url with value from href element

Tags: jquery

I need to add a parameter to my sites url from clicking on a link with the value of an a element.

Example:

```
<li><a href="Dell">Dell</a></li>
<li><a href="Dell">HP</a></li>
```

When the link is clicked I need to add ?fss=Dell to the url. The second click should add only the value in the a element: ?fss=Dell+HP and so on for each click. Then I need a reset click that removes everything - but keeps any parameter before ?fss=

There is also a scenario where I will have a parameter in place already, that looks like this: ?param=list, then I need the click to render this: 
?param=list&fss=HP where the word "list" can be a few different things.

Where do I start with this - I need it to be done trough Vanilla JS or jQuery.

Edit: someone posted this solution that worked perfectly - I only need to add an solution for a click that removes the fss and everything after it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').on('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(location.href.indexOf('?')===-1) location.href = location.href+"?   fss="+$(this).attr('href');
else location.href = location.href+"+"+$(this).attr('href');
});
});
```

Comment: should this make a request to the server with the new URL, or just rewrite it in the browser? What have you tried/researched so far?

Comment: I would recommend letting your user select all appropriate options in a multiselect or a tags type input then add the values to the URL and redirecting one time rather than adding parameters for each click. Better UX IMHO

Comment: Hi! Just a rewrite in the browser. I tried a bunch of different snippets, none worked as I wanted and I kinda got lost - So where unsure which progression I should post since i wasnt sure which one was the right path, so to speak.

Comment: Not sure why the previous solution was deleted? It worked great

Comment: it was downvoted by someone,  i have undeleted it

Comment: i have added the reset option too

Comment: Just saw it - it worked perfectly. May I ask - if I wanted to not add the the value, and simply replace it - what do change then? Just for an broader understanding of it. Thanks again!

Comment: i didn't actually understand . could you make it more clear?

Comment: Now the value for an example hp+dell, but if first click gives fss=hp - can i with the second click instead of adding the value next to HP, replace it? So first click ?fss=HP, then second would click would be ?fss=Dell, instead of ?fss=HP+Dell

Comment: If you always want dell to be on front, then href value has to be checked at first.. Just like the reset is compared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($(this).attr('href')!="reset"){
   if(location.href.indexOf('?')===-1) location.href = location.href+"?fss="+$(this).attr('href');
   else location.href = location.href+"+"+$(this).attr('href');
  }
  else location.href = location.origin+location.pathname;
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="Dell">dell</a>
<a href="Hp">hp</a>
<a href="reset">reset</a>
```